# how to update crate registry (index) using cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

using [cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/) (version 1.46.0 (04488afe3 2020-08-24)) or any other rust toolchain, what is the official way to force the update of the crate registry (crate.io index) without deleting manually `~/.cargo/registry/index`?

Comment: Performed within a crate, [`cargo update`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-update.html) will fetch the latest registry index prior to updating dependency versions in the lockfile.  If that's unsatisfactory then it's possible that the `--dry-run` or `--frozen` options will still update the registry index without modifying the crate's dependencies; or it's possible that running `cargo update` outside of a crate will still update the registry index before it fails—I don't know, I haven't investigated.

Comment: i am using cargo update but since it does not support update the registry on demand, i posted on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

I've done this by creating a temporary cargo project and adding a small dependency to it. Something like this:

```
mkdir /tmp/deleteme \
    && cd /tmp/deleteme \
    && cargo init \
    && cargo add serde \
    && rm -rf /tmp/deleteme
```

You should immediately see the message:

```
Updating crates.io index
```

Comment: `error: no such subcommand: add`

Comment: @Akito you need to update `cargo` to a newer version. `cargo add` was added last year https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#cargo-162-2022-06-30

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cargo update --dry-run` which refreshes both the index and git dependencies.

There is a tracking issue titled [Please provide a subcommand to refresh the crates.io index](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3377) in the cargo repository with a request to add dedicated command and alternative suggestions like running `cargo install lazy_static` which also updates the index and then does nothing because [`lazy_static` crate](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) does not provide binaries.